# Как сделать исключение?

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

Во время парсинга отелей, у одного из тегов 'a' нету класса(у остальных есть). Как мне сделать исключение?

код:

```
import requests
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

def get_data(url):
    headers = {
        'User Agent': 'Mozilla / 5.0(WindowsNT10.0; Win64;x64) AppleWebKit / 537.36(KHTML, likeGecko) Chrome / 110.0.0.0 Safari / 537.36'
    }

    req = requests.get(url=url)

    with open('index.html', 'w', encoding='utf8') as file:
        file.write(req.text)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')

    hotel_cards = soup.find_all('li', class_='item')
    #print(hotel_cards)
    for hotel_url in hotel_cards:
        hotel_url = 'https://101hotels.com' + hotel_url.find('a').get('href')
        #print(hotel_url)

    for title_hotels in hotel_cards:
        title_hotels = title_hotels.find('a', class_='has_query_params').text
        #print(title_hotels)

def main():
    get_data('https://101hotels.com/main/cities/yuzhno-sakhalinsk')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте привязаться к другому атрибуту, например,

```
title_hotels = title_hotels.find("a", {"itemprop": "url"}).text
```

или убрать атрибут вовсе

```
title_hotels = title_hotels.find("a").text
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!